# Declearing a string array in header

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang, clang-format

The code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *arr[1] = {"Hello"};
int main()
{
    printf("%s", arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the code does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *arr[1];
arr[0] = "Hello";
int main()
{
    printf("%s", arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the error

> warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘arr’ [-Wimplicit-int]
> main.c:4:1: error: conflicting types for ‘arr’; have ‘int[0]’

How does the assignments works out of the functions(i.e. in header files)?

type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘arr’ [-Wimplicit-int]

Comment: You cannot make assignments at global scope without it being part of a type declaration. The compiler is probably determining that you were trying to define a variable but were missing the type specifier, therefore it defaulted to `int`.

Comment: [tag:compiler-construction] has nothing to do with this question. You are not writing a compiler, and even if you were this is not a question about how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the assignments works out of the functions(i.e. in header files)?

They do not. Executable statements must be inside functions.

When the compiler is analyzing code outside of a function, it expects to find a declaration. So it is analyzing `arr[0] = "Hello";` as if it were a declaration. Declarations start with certain specifiers or qualifiers, such as `extern` for a storage-class specifier, `int` for a type specifier, or `const` for a type qualifier.

In the ancient history of C, `int` was taken as a default type, so, when the compiler does not find one of the specifiers or qualifiers it expects, it assumes `int` as a default. That is no longer part of the modern C standard, so the compiler warns you about it.

You cannot assign `"Hello"` to `arr[0]` outside of a function; there is no grammar for it in the C standard. You can only specify that `arr[0]` is to be initialized to `"Hello"` in the definition of `arr`.

You could put `arr[0] = "Hello";` inside the start of the `main` function so it would be executed when the program starts, but there is no reason to do that instead of using initialization.